# Как интегрировать gnuplot в LaTeX?

Tags: latex, gnuplot

Доброго времени суток.

Появилась нужна интегрировать gnuplot в LaTeX. Узнал про пакет gnuplottex. У меня стоит Windows 10. Я использую MikTeX и TeXstudio. Пытаюсь построить график - не получается. Выдает следующие ошибки:

> 'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

> 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

GNUPlot установлена. Сначала я думал нужно прописать путь к gnuplot, оказалось что прописывать ничего не нужно, gnuplot через консоль cmd открывается. Негде посмотрел, что нужно поставить в конфигурации TeXstudio --shell-escape, не помогло. Вот прикладываю скриншот результат вёрстки.

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для протокола, замечу, что я считаю плохой идеей таким способом строить графики. Во-первых, практически в любых книгах/документации по LaTeX/TeX пишут, что использовать `--shell-escape` опасно и лучше не стоит. Во-вторых, производить отладку или доводку рисунка до финальной версии удобнее в одной программе (gnuplot). Единственное положительное качество такого подхода - это использование шрифтов LaTeX. Но этого же результата можно добиться используя пакет `psfragx` или семейства пакетов `pstricks` или `tikz/pgf`.

Что касается пакета `gnuplottex`. Он был написан для дистрибутива teTeX (и его наследника TeXLive) для использования в системах Unix, поэтому он требует наличия команд `touch` и `rm` (и может, еще каких-то команд POSIX). Чтобы использовать этот пакет под MS Windows, как оказалось, достаточно задать опцию `[miktex]`. Иронично, что я использовал под MS Windows тот же TeXLive, но ему тоже требуется опция `miktex`.
Как вариант, вместо этой опции можно установить себе программы, типа MSYS, GnuWin32 или GoW, в которых реализуются команды из набора POSIX.

Пример рисунка я взял из документации пакета, но думаю, можно использовать и в том виде, как у автора вопроса. Параметры терминала можно задавать как в опциях окружения (как в примере из документации), так и внутри окружения, командами `gnuplot`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-1]
    \begin{figure}[h]%
        \centering%
        \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions=color dashed]
            set key box top left
            set key width 2
            set key opaque
            set sample 1000
            set xr [-5:5]
            set yr [-1:1]
            set xlabel '$x$-label'
            set ylabel '$y$-label'
            plot    sin(x) w l lc 1 lw 3 t '$\sin(x)$',\
                    cos(x) w l lc 2 lw 3 t '$\cos(x)$',\
                    tan(x) w l lc 3 lw 3 t '$\tan(x)$',\
                    tanh(x) w l lc 4 lw 3 t '$\tanh(x)$'
        \end{gnuplot}
        \caption{This is a simple example using the epslatex-terminal.}%
        \label{pic:epslatex}%
    \end{figure}%
    \lipsum[2-1]
\end{document}
```

Компиляцию производил и через `latex + dvips + ps2pdf` и через `pdflatex` (естественно, в обоих вариантах с опцией `--shell-escape`). В последнем случае, рисунок был автоматически преобразован из EPS в формат PDF.

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Владимир, добавление [miktex] в строчке \usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} помогло, спасибо. 

Вы сказали, что использование --shell-escape опасно. Теперь стало интересно, что может произойти. Скажите, пожалуйста.

Мне нужны графики в LaTeX, чтобы писать результат исследований научной деятельности. Здесь, как Вы подметили, можно использовать шрифт LaTeX. Хотя я могу строить графики в gnuplot. Я правильно понимаю, Вы имели ввиду, что можно построить график в gnuplot с использованием шрифтов LaTeX и потом вставить сохраненный график в документ .tex ?

Comment: @ddv,  --shell-escape опасно тем, что Вы почти не контролируете запуск сторонней программы и точно не можете предугадать, что будет сделано в результате. Если будете так компилировать чужой документ, можете сами запустить вирус или еще какую пакость. Выполнив программу с неверными опциями (да тот же `rm` можете и сами случайно навредить своей системе. Как-то так.

Comment: @ddv, О шрифтах... В gnuplot можно строить графики с теховскими шрифтами и командами, например, используя тот же терминал epslatex. Но я имел ввиду вообще другую возможность - специальным образом готовить рисунок в gnuplot (грубо говоря, все строки делать только латинскими буквами), а в документе latex через пакет psfragx подменять эти строки на необходимые надписи. А можно вообще накладывать текст (или даже делать части рисунков) на рисунок средствами пакетов pstricks или tikz.